# comparing element in arraylist with an integer value in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have loaded the contents of the database in an ArrayList named countList. The contents loaded are of int type. I created countList using the command

`ArrayList countList = new ArrayList();`

Now, I need to check if each contents of the arraylist is greater than three. I wrote it like

```
for(int i=0; i< itemset.size(); i++){
    if(countList.get(i) >= 3)
    {

    }
}
```

When I write it simply, it shows error of bad operand type for binary operator '>='. How to do the task?

Comment: What is supportcount and itemset in your code?

Comment: Where have you declared `supportcount` and `i`? If you have done the declaration correctly, there is not reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: i am sry for errors in the previous post. i have edited the code. itemset is also an arraylist. And i have loaded the two fields product_no and quantity of my database into itemset and countList.

Comment: Print out some items to standard output. See if they are numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `>=` operator is only defined on number types such as `int`, `double` or `Integer`, `Double`.  Now, `countlist` *may well* contain integers (I assume it does), but the way you have written your code, the compiler can't be sure.  This is because an `ArrayList` can store any type of object, including but not necessarily `Integer`.  There are a couple of ways you can remedy this:

a) You can **cast** the ArrayList item to an `Integer`, at which point the `>=` operator will work:

```
if ( (Integer) countList.get(i) >= 3)
```

b) You can use **generics** to tell the compiler that your `ArrayList` will ONLY store `Integer`s:

```
ArrayList<Integer> countList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(i=0; i< itemset.size(); i++){
   if (itemset.get(i) > 3) {
      // Do whatever you want here
   }
}
```

Comment: it does not work either. The above post is correct. I used generics as  jazzbassrob suggested and it absolutely works